# I can't create relationship in my database sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, insert

I have designed a  database for my website. It has 3 tables: user, topic and comment.

A user has many topics (or articles)
A topic (or article) has many comments
A user has many comments

I created the relationships for them  after I set the insert and and update specification as cascade.

I want that

- if I delete a user then the topics of this user and the user's comments will be deleted
- If I delete a topic then all comments of this topic will be delete by cascade

My diagram:

[image]

Comment: Please add the error you get when you try to define the foreign key constraints with the cascade option.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with creating two `CONSTRAINT` in `Comment` table with `ON DELETE CASCADE` one for `UserId` and other for `TopicId`, which can be fixed by `INSTEAD OF DELETE Trigger`. Just create all the tables and add all foreign key constraint as shown.

You can add your columns as indicated with other columns and `Id` column can be changed from bigInt to Int.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
UserId BIGINT NOT NULL,
UserName VARCHAR(10),
--Other columns
CONSTRAINT PkUserId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserId ASC) 
);
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Topic]
(
TopicId BIGINT NOT NULL,
UserId BIGINT NOT NULL,
TopicData VARCHAR(20)
--Other columns
CONSTRAINT PkpostId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(TopicId ASC)
);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Topic] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FkTopicUserId] FOREIGN KEY(UserId)
REFERENCES [dbo].[User]([UserId]);
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comment]
(
CommentId BIGINT NOT NULL,
TopicId BIGINT NOT NULL,
UserId BIGINT NOT NULL,
CommentData VARCHAR(20),
--Other columns
CONSTRAINT PkCommentId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(CommentId ASC)
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FkCommentTopic] FOREIGN KEY(TopicId)
REFERENCES [dbo].[Topic](TopicId);
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FkCommentUser] FOREIGN KEY(UserId)
REFERENCES [dbo].[User](UserId);
```

Now for Multiple delete cascade you can use [INSTEAD OF DELETE Triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DELETE_User]
   ON [dbo].[User]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DELETE FROM [dbo].[Topic] WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM  [dbo].[Comment] WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM dbo.[User] WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM DELETED)
END
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [DELETE_Topic]
   ON [dbo].[Topic]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DELETE FROM [dbo].[Topic] WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM  [dbo].[Comment] WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM DELETED)
END
GO
```

Let's check with some data on these the above design.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[User]
VALUES (1,'user1'),(2,'user2');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Topic]
VALUES (1,1,'POST1'), (2,1,'POST2'),(3,2,'POST3');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comment]
VALUES  (1,1,'COmment1'), (2,1,'Comment2'),
(3,1,'Comment3'), (4,2,'Comment4'), (5,3,'Comment4');
```

Now check with cascade delete.

```
SELECT UserId,UserName FROM [dbo].[User];
SELECT TopicId, UserId FROM [dbo].[Topic];
SELECT CommentId,TopicId FROM [dbo].[Comment];
GO
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Topic] WHERE TopicId =1;
GO
SELECT UserId,UserName FROM [dbo].[User];
SELECT TopicId, UserId FROM [dbo].[Topic];
SELECT CommentId,TopicId FROM [dbo].[Comment];
GO
DELETE FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE UserId = 2;
GO
SELECT UserId,UserName FROM [dbo].[User];
SELECT TopicId, UserId FROM [dbo].[Topic];
SELECT CommentId,TopicId FROM [dbo].[Comment];
```

Comment: You haven't created a `Comment -> User` foreign key.

Comment: @ypercube, Yes you are right edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: okey thank you :-D. I solve my problem :D